# ImportError: cannot import name 'testing' from 'tensorflow_datasets'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm unable to import tensorflow_datasets module into my jupyter notebook to do some deep learning on.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

This is the line where I get the error:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'testing' from 'tensorflow_datasets' (C:\Users\visha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets_*init*_.py)

Comment: Could you provide some more detail, like version, etc?

Comment: @AdityaMishra tensorflow version 2.0.0 and python version 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was an issue in installation of Tensorflow Datasets(TFDS). To install and use TFDS you should start with [getting started guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview).

To use `TensorFlow Datasets >=4.0.0` it requires TensorFlow version `>= 2.1.0`.

For `TF 2.0`, the compatible TFDS `<=3.2.1`. You can uninstall existing TFDS and install required version as shown below

```
!pip install tensorflow-datasets==3.2.1

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
print(tfds.__version__)
```

Output:

```
2.0.0
3.2.1
```